# Chromatic Number of KG(H)

Tags: coloring

Let $G$ be a graph with vertex set $2^{[n]}\setminus\emptyset $ which two of them are adjacent if and only if their intersection are empty. Determine the chromatic number of $G$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnesersConjecture.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But this problem is slightly different by Keneser's problem. Here I consider all non-empty subsets of $[n]$, not only k-subsets...

Answer (score 2):

Any function $f : 2^{[n]}\setminus \emptyset \to [n]$ such that $f(x) \in x$ gives a coloring with $n$ colors.
Since your graph contains $K_n$, you need at least $n$ colors, so the chromatic number is $n$.